# Python - How to change autopct text to white and bold in a pie chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to change the autopct text to bold and white.

If I insert textprops={'color':'white', 'weight':'bold', 'fontsize':12.5} in ax1.pie(..) the labels disappear.

Can someone help me please?

```
sizes1 = [3, 19]
explode1 = (0, 0.05)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,10))
labels = ('CRD = 1', 'CRD = 0')

#fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes1,explode= explode1, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
        shadow=False,startangle=40, colors=('tab:red', 'tab:blue'))
ax1.set_title('Frauen', fontdict={'fontsize': 17}, y=0.8)

ax1.axis('equal')

sizes2 = [10, 24]
explode2 = (0, 0.05)


ax2.pie(sizes2, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
        shadow=False,explode = explode2, startangle=345, colors=('tab:red','tab:blue'), )
ax2.set_title('Männer', fontdict={'fontsize': 17}, y=0.8)
ax2.axis('equal')
```

Pie Plots

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the `textprops` apply to both, the labels and the autopercentage texts, you need to format the autopercentage texts externally to the `pie` function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sizes1 = [3, 19]
explode1 = (0, 0.05)
labels = ('CRD = 1', 'CRD = 0')

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
_, _, autopcts = ax1.pie(sizes1,explode= explode1, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
        shadow=False,startangle=40, colors=('tab:red', 'tab:blue'))

plt.setp(autopcts, **{'color':'white', 'weight':'bold', 'fontsize':12.5})
ax1.set_title('Frauen', fontdict={'fontsize': 17})

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You are plotting white on white:**

In your case the labels disappear because you are setting the color to white  in the `textprops` argument. This is how you are doing it:

```
textprops={'color':'white', 'weight':'bold', 'fontsize':12.5}
```

and it plots **white labels on white background**, hence not seeng it. You can either:

**1. change the plot background color to a different color**

```
fig.set_facecolor('lightgrey')
```

[image: Image with a grey background]

or

**2. change the `textprops` color to something different**:

```
textprops={'color':"blue", 'size': 10, 'weight':'bold'}
```

[image: Blue textprop]

You can easily manage the font size, style and color using the `textprops` argument in the `ax.pie()` function.